# Inserting data into SQLITE database

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

I am trying to insert the data in SQLITE database but my application is crashing when I am trying to do so
here is my code
I am trying to insert data on Final click or radio button.
This is the insert block

```
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Log.d("Questions", "Moving to next question");
    a++;
    /**
     * validate a checkbox has been selected
     */
    if (!checkAnswer())
        return;

    /**
     * check if end of game
     */
    if (currentGame.isGameOver()) {
         db.open();

        String total = currentGame.getRight() + "";
        Log.i("Sanket", total);
        db.insertOptions(topic1, total, mon);
        db.close();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, EndgameActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        a = 0;
        finish();
    } else {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Here is my DatabaseAdapter Class
I have defined all methods here

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;

public class DBAdapter {


static final String topic = "topic";
static final String score = "score";
static final String month = "month";
static final String DATABASE_NAME = "questionDb";
static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "marks";
static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table marks"
        + "(topic text,score text,month text);";

final Context context;
DatabseHelper DBHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    DBHelper = new DatabseHelper(context);
}

    private static class DatabseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabseHelper(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("Sanket", "Upgrading database version from versin "
                + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
                + " which may cause to destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS marks");
        onCreate(db);
    }

}


public DBAdapter open() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DBHelper.close();
}

public long insertOptions(String topic1, String mon,
        String total) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

    initialValues.put(topic, topic1);
    initialValues.put(score, mon);
    initialValues.put(month, total);

    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);

}

Cursor getAllQuestions() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { topic, score, month },
            null, null, null, null, null);

}

long getNoOfRows() {
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE;
    SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement(sql);
    long count = statement.simpleQueryForLong();
    return count;
}

Cursor getAlldata() {
    String selectQuery = ("select * from marks");
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    return cursor;
}
```

}

Please go through my code and let me know the required changes

here is the LOGCAT

02-04 13:06:57.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1114): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 13:06:57.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1114): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
02-04 13:06:57.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
02-04 13:06:57.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:159)
02-04 13:06:57.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at com.tmm.android.chuck.QuestionActivity.onCheckedChanged(QuestionActivity.java:195)
02-04 13:06:57.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:174)
02-04 13:06:57.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.access$600(RadioGroup.java:54)
02-04 13:06:57.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.widget.RadioGroup$CheckedStateTracker.onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup.java:358)
02-04 13:06:57.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:129)
02-04 13:06:57.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:87)
02-04 13:06:57.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.widget.RadioButton.toggle(RadioButton.java:76)
02-04 13:06:57.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:99)
02-04 13:06:57.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
02-04 13:06:57.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-04 13:06:57.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-04 13:06:57.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-04 13:06:57.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-04 13:06:57.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 13:06:57.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-04 13:06:57.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-04 13:06:57.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-04 13:06:57.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1114):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: where is your code to create table .. please create table first

Comment: my table is already created do i need to create it again??

Comment: please post the error log here. It helps in better understanding the errors in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't created `marks` table in your `DBAdapter` class

create table

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    // creating required tables
    db.execSQL(TABLE_NAME);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // on upgrade drop older tables
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

    // create new tables
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Comment: any exceptions or warnings... @SanketNaik

Comment: no its just crashing the app
in logcat also no error
its just printing the value from TOPIC value which i have printed in LOG

Comment: @SanketNaik so here you posted wrong question. becoz crashing is not related to your question. You might go wrong some where else.

Comment: No bro if I comment that part 
insertion and log then the code is working

Comment: you are getting NullPointerException. check your these variables value before inseting them (topic1, total, mon) and also your db object. @SanketNaik

Answer (score 1):

Your database handler `onCreate()` is empty. Your database doesn't have any tables.

Put the required `CREATE TABLE` SQL there and uninstall your app so the old, empty database file is removed.

---

The exception stacktrace "println needs a message" you added to your question comes from here:

```
String total = currentGame.getRight() + "";
Log.i("Sanket", total);
```

because `total` is an empty string. Change the logging to something like

```
String total = currentGame.getRight() + "";
Log.i("Sanket", "total: " + total);
```

Comment: my database and tables already exits do i need to create it again with
this statement
db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

Comment: You must have an `onCreate()` that creates the tables you need.